# Archivos duplicados al leer archivo de texto linea a linea con java

Tags: java, string, loops

Mi preguntas es **¿por qué al leer un archivo `.txt` me duplica las lineas contenidas en mi .txt?** Es decir, si yo tengo una variable String la cual amaceno lo leído, por ej. juan, pedro, fulano. Si yo muestro en pantalla lo cargado en esa variable me imprime:

Salida:

> ```
> Juan
> Pedro
> Fulano
> Juan
> Pedro
> Fulano
> ```

He probado de distintas formas de leer un archivo y siempre obtengo el mismo resultado(duplicados).

#### Métodos que he probado con sus respectivas salidas

```
public void leer() {
        try {
            String ruta = "direccion";
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(ruta));
            String Cadena = "";
            while ((Cadena = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(Cadena);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

Salida:

> ```
> ALBERTO
> JUAN
> ALBERTO
> JUAN
> ```

```
public void leer() {
        try {
            String ruta = "ruta";
            Path path = Paths.get(ruta, ".txt");
            Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
            List<String> arrayTexto = new ArrayList<>();
            arrayTexto = Files.readAllLines(path, charset);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (String line : arrayTexto) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            System.out.println(builder);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Salida

> ```
> ALBERTO JUAN
> ALBERTO JUAN
> ```

```
public void leer() {
        try {
            String ruta = "ruta";
            Path path = Paths.get(ruta, ".txt");
            Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(path);
            stream.forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Salida

> ```
> ALBERTO
> JUAN
> ALBERTO
> JUAN
> ```

Como verán en cualquier método obtengo duplicados del contenido de mi `.txt` en el cual supongamos que tengo solamente **ALBERTO JUAN** dentro del mismo. Cual seria la causa de este problema?

Estoy utilizando Java 8. Desde ya agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Ya checaste el contenido del archivo?

Comment: Verifica desde donde mandas llamar al método.... puede que lo llames dos veces

Comment: De casualidad no tienes la función leer en un ciclo???

Comment: muestra como llamas a leer

Comment: @abrahamhs eres grande, sabelo! **ESO ERA COLEGA!!** Infinitas gracias! Si, lo estaba llamando dentro de un bugle `for` y por eso me duplicaba las lineas de mi archivo. Lo mande a llamar fuera del bucle y me leyo el contenido real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función como la describes es correcta, lo mas probable es que el error este en como la invocas. Revisa que el código que invoca esta función no este dentro de un bucle o en todo caso publicalo para ayudarte.

Para probar podrías ejecutar:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    leer();
}
```

Debería pintar sin repetir.

Comment: Correcto colega! Era porque la estaba llamando dentro de un bugle `for`